# Pandas Groupby, Filter, and Insert Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Pandas dataframe that has a column with a unique ID code representing a client. Each ID code is repeated in several rows in the table. There is another column in the table with a boolean flag, true or false. I am trying to adjust the table so that for every ID code, if there is at least one flag set to true, they will all be set to true; i.e. you could have one client ID code in 10 rows, and 9 of the rows have the flag set to false but one is set to true. I want all of the rows to now get set to true. Here is what I tried:

````
data=[
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":False},
    {"id":"b","flag":False},
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":True}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x:(x['flag']==True).any())['mod_flag'] = True```

df[df['mod_flag'] != True] = False
````

But it is throwing a key error on the second line for `mod_flag`. Any help would be greatly appreciated--thanks!

EDIT:

Adding in a sample data table here for the desired output:

| id | flag | mod_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | False | False |
| a | False | False |
| b | False | True |
| b | False | True |
| b | True | True |
| c | True | True |
| c | True | True |

Where the rows with ID = b are the ones that need to be changed.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Comment: Sorry about that @Prune, the edits have been made. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but your edits do not address the problems.  Please follow the information in the links I provided.

Comment: How about now? @Prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `groupby()` to get all related rows together
- `transform()` to get a value for each work
- simple pandas series `any()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"client_id":np.random.randint(1,5,8),
             "flag":np.random.choice([False,True], 8)}).sort_values("client_id")

df.assign(newflag=df.groupby("client_id")["flag"].transform(lambda s: s.any()))
```

|  | client_id | flag | newflag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | True | True |
| 6 | 1 | False | True |
| 0 | 2 | True | True |
| 2 | 2 | True | True |
| 7 | 2 | True | True |
| 1 | 3 | True | True |
| 4 | 3 | False | True |
| 5 | 4 | False | False |

Comment: This worked perfectly--thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```py
data=[
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":False},
    {"id":"b","flag":False},
    {"id":"a","flag":True},
    {"id":"a","flag":True}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


true_ids = df[df["flag"]]["id"].unique()
df["flag"] = df["id"].isin(true_ids)
```